# Why Flow cannot call ReactDOM.render with document.getElementById(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I was getting this error below in Flow type checking.

```
Cannot call ReactDOM.render with document.getElementById(...) bound to container because null [1] is
incompatible with Element [2].

     src/index.js
      26│       </Switch>
      27│     </ScrollToTop>
      28│   </BrowserRouter>
      29│ </Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
      30│

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_174a8121/dom.js
 [1] 646│   getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null;

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_174a8121/react-dom.js
 [2]  18│     container: Element,
```

The code is below.

```
// @flow
"use strict";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Detail from "./components/detail";
import LevelOfGame from "./components/level-of-game";
import NotFound from "./components/not-found";
import ScrollToTop from "./components/scroll-to-top";

import reducers from "./reducers";

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/detail/:detailId" component={Detail}/>
        <Route path="/level-of-game" component={LevelOfGame}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}/>
      </Switch>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I believe I had to specify the type somehow in `getElementById`.

So I fixed the error by storing `document.getElementById("root");` in a constant variable with a type specification:

```
const root: any = document.getElementById("root");
```

The error is fixed and I hope this is useful for other folks, but I'd love to understand what was causing this error. Can anyone be so kind to tell me what this was?

Comment: As the error says `document.getElementById` can return `null` and `ReactDOM.render` typing doesn't allow it. So to fix the error you could just verify that `root` has value: `const root = document.getElementById("root"); if (root) ReactDOM.render(...`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) got this first in the comments, I wanted to bring this info up to the answer level for easier visual scanning.

Flow is letting you know that the call `document.getElementById("root");` can return `null` in which case the app would completely crash. So let's guard against that:

```
const root = document.getElementById('root')

if (root !== null) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App /> , root)
}
```

Granted, this can feel a little annoying given that in all likelihood you will be controlling the HTML you are rendering into.

Answer (score 5):

While Cogell's answer is correct, I would argue to keep the code simpler and add an exception.

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/detail/:detailId" component={Detail}/>
        <Route path="/level-of-game" component={LevelOfGame}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}/>
      </Switch>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </BrowserRouter>
 </Provider>, // $FlowIgnore
 document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Notice the "$FlowIgnore" comment

and then in your `.flowconfig` file add this to the "options" field:

`suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIgnore`