# React JSX component. Can't pass flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have following code working as expected:

```
import Button from "./components/Button"
import Excel from "./components/Excel";
import Logo from "./components/Logo";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, {Component} from "react";

type Props = {};
type State = {};

class Parent extends Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)
    }

    triggerJson() {
        this.excel.exportJSON();
    }
    triggerCsv() {
        this.excel.exportCSV();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{display: "inline-block", background: "purple"}}>
                    <Logo/>
                </div>
                <h1> Welcome to The App!^^!</h1>
                <div>
                    <Button onClick={this.triggerJson.bind(this)}>Export JSON</Button>
                    <Button onClick={this.triggerCsv.bind(this)}>Export CSV</Button>
                </div>
                <Excel ref={excel => this.excel = excel} headers={headers} initialData={data} search={true}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But trying to pass `flow` (installed with `npm install flow-bin`) checking gives me following errors:

```
Cannot get this.excel because property excel is missing in Parent [1].
```

and

```
Cannot assign excel to this.excel because property excel is missing in Parent [1].
```

I need to call `Excel's` functions `exportJSON` and `exportCSV` by buttons clicking. How should I modify this code to pass `flow` control?

Another one error I got is:

```
Cannot call ReactDOM.render with document.getElementById(...) bound to container because null [1] is incompatible with
Element [2].
```

Comment: don't you have to bind the functions to the class ? You can to do it in es6 classes.

Comment: Pranay Tripathi , how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need something like the following:

```
class Parent extends Component<Props, State> {
   excel: whateverTheTypeOfThisShouldBe;
   ... (the rest of your class)
```

This declares `excel` as a property of your `Parent` class.

Comment: yeah, ```excel: Excel;``` removed first two ```flow``` errors. Thank you!
Last one explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596022/why-flow-cannot-call-reactdom-render-with-document-getelementbyid